# It is OK to do in this way? (dispatch store) Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a question.
For example, I have the following code:

//Actions

```
 export function getNews () {
   return Api.getNews()
       .then((response) => {
       if (typeof response !== 'undefined') {
        return MainStore.dispatch(NewsActionCreators.getNews(response));
       }
     })
     .catch((error) => // some logic);
}
```

//ActionsCreator

```
import { NewsConstants } from 'front/constants/NewsConstants';

import { Action } from 'redux-actions';

export function getNews(payload): Action {
    return {
        type: NewsConstants.NEWS_RECEIVED,
        payload,
    };
}
```

//Component

```
import * as NewsActions from 'front/actions/NewsActions';

componentDidMount() {
    getNews();
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
       news: state.News.getIn(['news']),
   };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {};
};
```

//MainStore

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore, Store} from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import { Reducers} from 'front/reducers/index';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
let middleware;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    middleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware(), routerMiddleware(history), logger, thunk);
} else {
    middleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware(), routerMiddleware(history), thunk);
}

export const MainStore:Store<any> = createStore<any>(
    Reducers,
    middleware,
);
```

This works fine. But I just want to know is this the correct way? Or I need to call all actions by **mapDispatchToProps** inside components? 
Thanks :)

Updated. Added MainStore

Comment: You can call dispatch elsewhere. But make sure that you are dispatching to the same store. In your api code, you use `MainStore`, but where do you get that from?

Comment: mapDispatchToProps is simply syntactical sugar, and is the same as calling store.dispatch(action(data)). There are no great benefits to it other than it looks nicer + you don't have to import your store

Comment: Thanks. I ask it because in project with React Native and redux (It was my first project on React Native) Reviewer said that it is mistake call actions in this way.

Comment: Kind of off-topic, but your `getNews` function has a common antipattern. If you write `Api.getNews().then(doStuff).catch(handleErrors)`, any errors that happen as a result of the dispatch are swallowed into the handleErrors handler. What you propably want is `Api.getNews().then(doStuff, handleErrors)`, so that handleErrors gets called for any errors from `getNews()` but not from `doStuff`.

Comment: @OlliM, yeah i know, some functions was cutted just for example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miguel already answered your question. But I think a better way to handle mapDispatchToProps that is worth mentioning here: You can pass these action creators directly to the react-redux connect function like this: `{ actionCreator1, actionCreator2 }`, or you can import all of the action creators `import * as newActions` and then spread them into the connect function like this `{ ...newActions }`.

```
...
import { getNew } from 'front/actions/NewsActions';

class News extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getNews();
  }

  render() { ... }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    news: state.News.getIn(['news']),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateTopProps, {
  getNews,
})(News);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Did you mean to have mapStateToProps as a class property? never seen that before

Comment: Woooops, I didn't move it out of the class. Fixed, Thanks!

Comment: But action and actioncreator will looks the same as in my example? or i need some changes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to pass action creators to the component as props by means of `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getNews();
}

...

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({getNews: () => dispatch(getNews())})
```

Comment: Or simply `const mapDispatchToProps = { getNews }`

Comment: Thanks. But as i understand it is just syntactical sugar.
it is nor error or something bad for perfomance